# How to replace in PHP all matches of a digit plus a space with comma in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

```
$str = "Hello 1234567 Stack 56789 Overflow 12345";

$str = preg_replace('/([0-9] )/', ',', $str);
```

I want this "Hello 1234567, Stack 56789, Overflow 12345,..."

Comment: Your expected output is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
preg_replace('/\d(?=\s)/', '$0,', $str)
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6W4pEjBVkHJIzUnJ1/B0MjYxNTMXCG4JDE5WwHIsrBU8C9LLUrLyS@HSCpZc6UmZ@QrFBSlpscXpRbkJCanaqjrx6Ro2NvGFGvqq@soqKsY6AApkMma1v//AwA).

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex logic which explicitly targets spaces with numbers to the left and letters to the right:

```php
$input = "Hello 1234567 Stack 56789 Overflow 12345";
$output = preg_replace('/(?<=\d) (?=\D)/', ', ', $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
Hello 1234567 Stack 56789 Overflow 12345
Hello 1234567, Stack 56789, Overflow 12345
```